# GtkStack segmentation fault

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I've made a simple program to learn how to work with the GtkStack Widget.  The program is supposed to switch stack pages when the button is clicked.  However when the button is clicked the program terminates with the error `segmentation fault` I am very new to both C and GTK and can't seem to understand why this isn't working.

OS: Debian 9.6 with Gnome 3.22.2

C Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct _MyStruct
{
    GtkWidget *mainWindow;
    GtkWidget *myStack;
    GtkWidget *page0;
    GtkWidget *page1;
    GtkWidget *buttonPage0;
    GtkWidget *buttonPage1;
}   MyStruct;

static void clickedButtonPage0(GtkWidget *widget, MyStruct *mrp)
{
    gtk_stack_set_visible_child (GTK_STACK(mrp->myStack), mrp->page1);
}

static void clickedButtonPage1(GtkWidget *widget, MyStruct *mrp)
{
    gtk_stack_set_visible_child (GTK_STACK(mrp->myStack), mrp->page0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    MyStruct mrp;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "stackTest.glade", NULL);

    mrp.mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "myWindow"));
    g_signal_connect(mrp.mainWindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    mrp.myStack = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "myStack"));
    mrp.page0 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "page0"));
    mrp.page1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "page1"));

    mrp.buttonPage0 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "buttonPage0"));
    mrp.buttonPage1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "buttonPage1"));

    g_signal_connect(mrp.buttonPage0, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clickedButtonPage0), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(mrp.buttonPage1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clickedButtonPage1), NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mrp.mainWindow), 600, 400);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(mrp.mainWindow), "GtkStack Test");

    gtk_widget_show_all(mrp.mainWindow);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Glade XLM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="myWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkStack" id="myStack">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="page0">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="lblPage0">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">I am page 0</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="buttonPage0">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page0</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="page1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="lblPage1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">I am Page 1</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="buttonPage1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Home</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page1</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page1</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc stackTest.c -o stackTest `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: This is a good time to start learning how to use a debugger. Run your program in GDB and you will immediately see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger tells you where the segmentation fault happens:

```
gtk_stack_set_visible_child (GTK_STACK(mrp->myStack), mrp->page1);
```

Only used variable is `mrp`. This variable is `NULL`.

And it is `NULL` because you provide only a `NULL` pointer:

```
g_signal_connect(mrp.buttonPage0, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clickedButtonPage0), NULL);
g_signal_connect(mrp.buttonPage1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(clickedButtonPage1), NULL);
```

Replace `NULL` with `&mrp` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me not only the problem but how you found the problem.  You've been a huge help.